# PCB layout - part placement note in draftsman drawing

Tags: altium

I am preparing to transfer a schematic project to a layout person. I'd like to include a note in a draftsman drawing detailing an area where a component must go on the PCB to avoid interference from other external parts in the product but not on the PCB. I thought I could make a draftsman document, draw a rectangle in the correct area (that is larger than the part) and then add dimensions from the PCB origin to the vertices of the rectangle. Altium isn't allowing me to dimension to a rectangle or any object that I add in draftsman view.

How do I do it?

Comment: I can dimension the rectangle I added but I cannot dimension from the board edge to the rectangle edge

Comment: Don't you have a list of instructions that go to the draftsman as part of your normal drafting/layout/routing process?  Routing rules, layer stackup, that sort of stuff?  The information should go there.